# Pipeline scheduling doubts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have several pipelines in my project, and I need to schedule them in specific dates.

- Is it possible to execute a pipeline every 11th day?
- Is it possible to visualize all the pipelines in the project and see the next one to be executed or a table or something with all the pipelines schedules the way I'm working is the "classic view" not YAML.

I am sorry if the doubts seem dumb or something, but I'm searching and I can't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in YAML cause a pipeline to run on a schedule defined using [cron syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#supported-cron-syntax):

```
mm HH DD MM DW
 \  \  \  \  \__ Days of week
  \  \  \  \____ Months
   \  \  \______ Days
    \  \________ Hours
     \__________ Minutes
```

So, if you want it will run every 11th of the month, you can achieve in this syntax:

```
0 0 11 * *
```

In your YAML:

```
schedules: 
- cron: "0 0 11 * *"   # replace with your schedule
```

You can use [this](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_11_*_*) site to check the syntax.

Regarding your second question, I'm afraid that impossible with YAML pipelines, there is no "table" or something :/

But, it's a good idea, I suggest you create a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Comment: Wow! thank you so much!! i'll check into it, i've never used yaml, is there a way to do it with the classic view? thank so much again!

Comment: Oh I thought you use yaml, in the classic view I don’t think you have an option for specific date on month :/